# jsoauth twitter data empty

Tags: jquery, oauth, twitter

I'm new to ajax and more specifically oauth and don't quite understand why my response is returning empty. I've read the api docs for this method http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/home_timeline.json but can't seem to retrieve nodes from the response. I'm guessing my request is valid because the failure callback isn't called but I just don't understand why the response appears to be empty. I commented out the JSON.parse(data.text) because it was throwing an unexpected end of data error. I'm using the JsOauth Library.

```
function success(data){
    // var timeline = JSON.parse(data.text);
    $.each(data, function (element){
        console.log(element.created_at);
    });
}

function failure(data) {
    alert("Something went wrong!");
}

oauth.get("http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/home_timeline.json", success, failure);
```

Thanks for any insight,

J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly what platform are you attempting to make the call? I've encountered many people trying to use jsOAuth in the browser, yet dispite its name its meant to be used in javascript application frameworks like air, phonegap or titanium.

Cross site scripting protection on browsers requires that any access via AJAX to a server other than the original host requires something known as CORS, something twitter doesnt support.

Hope this helps. I'm on twitter @bytespider if you require more help.

Comment: Yep, you were right. When used as a python view it worked, thanks!